# pointer to class created error core dump

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a template class. It seems to be ok, but when I try to create a pointer to myclass' object, a core dumped error occurs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T>
class vec {
private:
    T* m_pnt;
    int m_dim;

public:
    vec();
    vec(int);
    ~vec();

    void prnt();
    void reduce(int);
    void null();

    void set(int, T);
    void print();
};

template <typename T>
vec<T>::vec() {
    m_dim = 100;
    m_pnt = (T*)calloc(100, sizeof(T));
    std::cout << "building without par" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
vec<T>::vec(int n) {
    m_dim = n;
    m_pnt = (T*)calloc(m_dim, sizeof(T));
    std::cout << "building" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
vec<T>::~vec() {
    free(m_pnt);
    std::cout << "killed" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void vec<T>::reduce(int dim) {
    std::cout << "reduce" << std::endl;
    if (dim <= m_dim) {
        m_dim = dim;
        T* p = (T*)calloc(m_dim, sizeof(T));
        for (int i = 0; i != m_dim; i++)
            *(p + i) = *(m_pnt + i);

        free(m_pnt);

        m_pnt = p;
    } else {
        std::cout << "error: rowvector not valid dimension" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void vec<T>::set(int idx, T val) {
    if (idx >= 1 && idx <= m_dim)
        *(m_pnt + idx - 1) = val;
    else {
        std::cout << "error: rowvector not valid index" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void vec<T>::prnt() {
    for (int i = 0; i != m_dim; i++)
        std::cout << i + 1 << "\t" << m_pnt + i << "\t" << *(m_pnt + i)
                  << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void vec<T>::null() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m_dim; i++)
        *(m_pnt + i - 1) = T(0);
}

int main() {
    vec<int>* d;
    std::cout << "d: " << d << std::endl;
    d->prnt();

    return 0;
}
```

There are no error in compiling, but the final output is something like

```
    d: 0
    segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `calloc` does not work for any `T`.

Comment: `There are no error in compiling` I see this written so many times, that "there is no error in compiling".  All you did when you compiled successfully is produce a program that is *syntactically* correct.  It doesn't guarantee at all that the program will run correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You never allocated your pointer:

```
vec<int>* d = new vec<int>;
```

You current code:

```
vec<int>* d;
```

Just defines a variable `d` holding a pointer to a `vec<int>` object. But it points to nowhere. To make it points to *something* you must build a `vec<int>` in memory using `new vec<int>`

Answer (score 1):

1. you should use C++ style allocation and de-allocation (`new` and
   `delete`) instead of `calloc` and `free`. This is to ensure apropriate alignment.
2. you should not use `int` to hold the size of your vector, but an unsigned type. The C++ standard is to use `std::size_t`.
3. you cannot expect an uninitialised pointer (`d`) to point to
   anything useful. Hence using it will cause an error (or worse:
   nonsensical behaviour).
4. Have a look at any implementation of `std::vector<>` to see how things are done professionally.
5. Your code is not exception safe: if allocation with `calloc` fails, `m_dim` still shows the initial dimensionality.

Comment: `calloc` doesn't call constructors.

Comment: ok, thx. But where can I find implementation of std::vector<>?

Comment: @user3918990 - `#include <vector>` and take a look inside of that header file. Also, creating usable classes like this is not a trivial matter.  You are making basic mistakes that look akin to a C programmer attempting to create a C++ class for the first time (using `calloc` for example).  If I took your code and attempted to do `vec<std::string>`, it would blow up due to `calloc` not able to actually construct objects.